# Perl5 compatible regular expression to retrieve some values in the middle of xml

Tags: xml, regex, perl

I want a regular expression (Perl5-compatible regular expressions) to retrieve a tag value based on some other tag value inside a xml. For example, I have a xml as below in which I want to retrieve customerid and participationtype tag values only if the participationtype tag value is either clmt or insrd.

I have tried the following expression which is not working when the order of the tags are not matching the expression. Because the tags may be in any order.

I have tried the following which is not working when the order of the tags change.

```
<ASObject mappedClass="com.taliantsoftware.insurance.participation.ParticipantSummaryDTO">([^^]*?)<customerid tagClass="double">(.*)</customerid>([^^]*?)<participationtype tagClass="String">(clmt|insrd)</participationtype>([^^]*?)</ASObject>
```

XML is here:

```
<participantsummarydtos tagClass="object-array">
            <ASObject mappedClass="com.taliantsoftware.insurance.participation.ParticipantSummaryDTO">
              <customertype tagClass="String">prsn</customertype>
              <linkednoteindicator tagClass="boolean">false</linkednoteindicator>
              <new tagClass="boolean">true</new>
              <customerid tagClass="double">3209053.0</customerid>
              <participationtype tagClass="String">clmt</participationtype>
              <updated tagClass="boolean">true</updated>
              <voided tagClass="boolean">false</voided>
              <blockexist tagClass="boolean">false</blockexist>
              <participationid tagClass="double">2664273.0</participationid>
              <customername tagClass="String">MELISSA M. CORNWELL</customername>
              <customerphonenumber tagClass="String">3303660069</customerphonenumber>
              <effectivedate tagClass="Date">1997-03-02 19:00:00.0 EST</effectivedate>
            </ASObject>
            <ASObject mappedClass="com.taliantsoftware.insurance.participation.ParticipantSummaryDTO">
              <participationtype tagClass="String">clmt_atty</participationtype>
              <blockexist tagClass="boolean">false</blockexist>
              <customertype tagClass="String">busn</customertype>
              <linkednoteindicator tagClass="boolean">false</linkednoteindicator>
              <new tagClass="boolean">true</new>
              <customerid tagClass="double">8017633.0</customerid>
              <updated tagClass="boolean">true</updated>
              <voided tagClass="boolean">false</voided>
              <customerfaxnumber tagClass="String">3307433451</customerfaxnumber>
              <participationid tagClass="double">8.841391E7</participationid>
              <effectivedate tagClass="Date">1997-05-28 20:00:00.0 EDT</effectivedate>
              <customername tagClass="String">GREEN HAINES SGAMBATI CO, LPA</customername>
              <customerphonenumber tagClass="String">3307435101</customerphonenumber>
            </ASObject>
            <ASObject mappedClass="com.taliantsoftware.insurance.participation.ParticipantSummaryDTO">
              <participationtype tagClass="String">emp_rep</participationtype>
              <blockexist tagClass="boolean">false</blockexist>
              <customertype tagClass="String">busn</customertype>
              <linkednoteindicator tagClass="boolean">false</linkednoteindicator>
              <new tagClass="boolean">true</new>
              <customerid tagClass="double">8021870.0</customerid>
              <updated tagClass="boolean">true</updated>
              <voided tagClass="boolean">false</voided>
              <customerfaxnumber tagClass="String">6147666888</customerfaxnumber>
              <enddate tagClass="Date">2011-01-04 19:00:00.0 EST</enddate>
              <participationid tagClass="double">7.7477885E7</participationid>
              <effectivedate tagClass="Date">2010-04-11 20:00:00.0 EDT</effectivedate>
              <customerphonenumber tagClass="String">8008256755</customerphonenumber>
              <customername tagClass="String">COMPMANAGEMENT, INC.</customername>
            </ASObject>
            <ASObject mappedClass="com.taliantsoftware.insurance.participation.ParticipantSummaryDTO">
              <participationtype tagClass="String">insrd</participationtype>
              <blockexist tagClass="boolean">false</blockexist>
              <customertype tagClass="String">busn</customertype>
              <linkednoteindicator tagClass="boolean">false</linkednoteindicator>
              <new tagClass="boolean">true</new>
              <customerid tagClass="double">1011089.0</customerid>
              <updated tagClass="boolean">true</updated>
              <voided tagClass="boolean">false</voided>
              <customerfaxnumber tagClass="String">3305452444</customerfaxnumber>
              <participationid tagClass="double">1.7638265E7</participationid>
              <effectivedate tagClass="Date">1997-03-02 19:00:00.0 EST</effectivedate>
              <customername tagClass="String">OMNI MANOR, INC</customername>
              <customerphonenumber tagClass="String">3305451550</customerphonenumber>
            </ASObject>
          </participantsummarydtos>
```

Comment: Simple: Don't use regexes. Use XPath. This is exactly the type of query it's designed for.

Comment: I have tried below XPath, but not able to write expression to identify sub tags  customerid and participationtype........<ASObject mappedClass="com.taliantsoftware.insurance.participation.ParticipantSummaryDTO">([^^]*?)<customerid tagClass="double">(.*)</customerid>([^^]*?)<participationtype tagClass="String">(clmt|insrd)</participationtype>([^^]*?)</ASObject>

Comment: `//participationtype[text()="clmt"]/..` will give you every ASObject that has a `clmt` participationtype. from there you can get your other tags quite easily.

Comment: My tool cannot take XPath expression in the above format. It can only take it as shown here...so I added like this but it is not working, moreover I want to match either clmt or insrd inside participationtype  [code] ActionMessage/bodies[1]/MessageBody[1]/data[1]/result[1]/participantsummarydtos[1]/ASObject[*]/participationtype[text()="clmt"][/code]

Comment: I have got the solution by writing XPath as below.

    //ASObject[participationtype='clmt']/customerid/text()|//ASObject[participationtype='insrd']/customerid/text() 

Now I am getting the result as 

3209053.0

1011089.0

But I want the result as 

clmt,3209053.0

insrd,1011089.0

How to get the matched condition value itself in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution by using both XPath and Regex as below.

First, I have used the XPath to get all ASObject tags which has participation type as either clmt or  insrd.

```
//ASObject[participationtype='clmt']/|//ASObject[participationt‌​ype='insrd']
```

After that, I have used regex to get participationtype and customerid tag values from the XPath result irrespective of their position.

```
(?s)\A(?=.*<customerid[^>]*>([^<>]*)</customerid>)(?=.*<participationtype[^>]*>([^<>]*)</participationtype>)
```

so, the final result would be {[clmt,3209053.0], [insrd,1011089.0]}